# How to assign Boolean value to model

Tags: angularjs

I have the following view with two input radio buttons:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="fooBar" 
        value="true" ng-change="logConsole()">
    True
</label>

<label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="fooBar" 
        value="false" ng-change="logConsole()">
    False
</label>
```

And my controller looks like:

```
//Initialization
$scope.fooBar = false;

$scope.logConsole = function () {
    console.log("Value is : " + $scope.fooBar);
    console.log("Type is : " + typeof $scope.fooBar); //Always displays 'string'
};
```

My problem is that when the user selects either of the radio buttons, the type of the `fooBar` model is always a String, that is the value is either the String 'true' or the String 'false' - I want the type to be a boolean true value or a boolean false value.
How can I store a boolean value (from within the view) onto the model?

EDIT: I just tried this out and it still does not work. For the `value` attribute, I passed a function that would return boolean true or false, something like this:

```
<input type="text" value="{{getBoolean('true')}}....>
```

$scope.getBoolean = function (value) {
    if (value === 'true') return true;
    else return false;
};

It still results in a String when the radio buttons are selected...

Comment: try to take out the value attribute.  Let angular bind in the current value of fooBar.

Comment: @DavinTryon No, does not work. The model gets an `undefined` value.

Comment: why dont u just use value=true

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal Still returns a String true and not a Boolean true...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

One of the comments in [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.radio) says:

> While ng-value is not documented, it is a useful directive, specifically when you are binding to a boolean value.

```
<input ng-model="foo" type="radio" value="true">
```

> may not work but

```
<input ng-model="foo" ng-value="true" type="radio">
```

> does.

Comment: Awesome! Hadn't heard of this directive before... And I don't seem to be able to see the discussions for that documentation...

Comment: Too bad. They must probably be blocked by your company firewall. You should ask to unblock them, because many valuable things can be found in the comments.